# Floating divs goes down when page is resized

Tags: html, css

I have a main div, and inside it..I have 3 divs

In normal view it works perfect i need the exact samething but for some reason if i resize my browser one div at the right side will float down i figure the reason for it but i don't know how to resolve it . floating down of div is due to the border i have give to the div but i have given the borders with perfect calculations but i don't know why still it happens

**HTML**

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_top"></div>
    <div class="box_left"></div>
    <div class="box_right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.box{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
.box_top{
    width:500px;
    height:49px;
    border-bottom:rgb(239,239,239) 1px solid;
    background-color:#636;
}
.box_left{
    width: 249px;
    height: 250px;
    float:left;
    background-color: #093;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #FFF;   
}
.box_right{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#006;
}
```

please go hear for the issue : http://jsfiddle.net/gtczu/

Comment: Not happening in Chrome. What browser is it happening with?

Comment: I don't seen an issue in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and IE9

Answer (score 2):

Add `min-width: 500px;` to `.box`, when the browser window gets smaller than 500px, the horizontal scrollbar will appear.

Check your [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtczu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are floating left without having a width set on the container. I would set a min-width or just a width on the containing div.

Comment: .box container has a width of 500px

Answer (score 0):

this is because the total width of all your inner divs  get larger than the view port size when it is resized....thats why the last div is floating down when resized.try to express all width in percentage..i think this trick may work